# Probability of drawing balls from a box

Tags: probability

There are four red and six blue balls in a box. Three balls are drawn from the box randomly. What is the probability of drawing at least two red balls?

This seems pretty simple but I can't seem to find the right answer for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Three balls can be drawn from the box in a total $\binom{10}{3}$ ways. Now, the no. of ways the three balls can have at least $2$ red balls is $\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{4}{3}$. The first factor is due to $2$ red one blue and the next factor is due to all three red.
So, probability is $$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{1}+\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If you draw at least two red balls, you must have drawn one of $\def\R{\color{maroon}{R}}\def\B{\color{darkblue}{B}}\R\R\R, \R\R\B, \R\B\R,$ or $\B\R\R$.  These are exclusive.  What is the probability of each?